# where is vsftpd root directory on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: permissions, home-directory, vsftpd

Where is vsftpd home directory located on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and where does it store files?

Comment: Look at `/var/log/xferlog`, read `man vsftpd;man vsftpd.conf`

Comment: `/var/log/xferlog`: no such file exist in my /var/log/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your configuration - see [man vsftpd.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html). There are two major cases:

- By default the anonymous log-in is not enabled. So you must log-in with a system user. For example if you are logging-in with `user1` you will be redirected to its `$HOME` directory, that should be `/home/user1/`.
- If you have enabled the anonymous log-in by the option directive `anonymous_enable`, you must specify also `anon_root`. For example, to enamle the minimal anonymous configuration:

  - Add these two lines to `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

    ```
    anonymous_enable=Yes
    anon_root=/home/ftp/
    ```
  - Create the directory and restart the service:

    ```
    sudo mkdir /home/ftp/
    sudo systemctl restart vsftpd.service
    ```
  - Note with this configuration the users are not permitted to upload files. This is more complicated task...

Comment: The `/etc/vsftpd.conf` have `anonymous_enable=NO`, `write_enable=YES` both uncommented, there is dedicated user with password. But I can't find file in `/home/user/` directory. Possibly the transfer was unsuccessful, although the `/var/log/vsftpd.log` show user login ` [user] OK LOGIN: Client "IP address"`.

Comment: @fxgreen, unfortunately `vfsftpd` doesn't write logs for the denied operations. Here is how my log file looks like after successful upload: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KG4PgFZNkP/. How did you create the `user` and `/home/user/`? I mean, does the `user` is a owner of `/home/user/`?

Comment: I don't remember how I created the ftp user, but it has the following permissions:
`$ ls -ld /home/user1ftp`
`drwxr-xr-x 16 user1ftp user1ftp 4096 Jun  9 14:45 /home/user1ftp`.